# set multiple values in a select from string

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have this string:

```
var product = "bj,tg,ap,nl";
```

Now I´d like jQuery to select these values in a `select2` option list. I know how to select just one:

```
$('#product').val('bj').trigger('change.select2');`
```

But how do i select all the comma separated values from that string? I guess it should look like:

```
$('#product').val('bj', 'tg', 'ap').trigger('change.select2');
```

So I need to put some `'` and spaces into my string "product". How would i do that? Can i use regex?

Comment: Can you provide a title that remotely matches what your asking please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method accepts an array for `multiple` option. You can use `split()` to create an array and pass it to `.val()` method.

```
$('#product').val(product.split(',')).trigger('change.select2');
```

Comment: Awesome. I like it when it´s this easy! Working like a charm. Thanks a lot!